# Minimalizing a logo

Tags: logo, minimalistic

I would like to redesign this logo to make it more minimal and understandable, but am failing to do so.

***What are some key points I could follow to achieve this task?***

Software: Illustrator

Logo for Technological Fest

| Initial logo | What I tried |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

### Edit: update

Here is what I tried keeping in mind the answers and points provided here. This works well in black/white contrast while retaining familiarity. Anything else that can be done to complete the minimalization of this logo?
[image]

Comment: Try two colors approach? Like you reduced from four to three. Right now there are three colors. Maybe that will help in a possible tweak to make it minimal?

Comment: Problem is that your logo does not work in black and white.

Comment: @joojaa good point. But I'm noticing more and more clients want more colorful and non-flat logos these days. I don't know if it's true for my country but I'm noticing same. Many will fail if we apply black and white.

Comment: @Vikas you are the expert, you will design a logo that can do both because thats just the way things work. Human visual system is mainly contrast based so having a full contrast logo design ensures best possible recognizability, readability possible. This ensures the logo is clean, usable in small sizes (think pens), usable on wide variety of mediums, think etched on metal, silkscreened on a PCB, vinyl cut on window. Also think that even apple a trillion dollar company can not afford to not have a 2 color logo, can you really...

Comment: [It's quite true for my country but not sure about others] Typo correction above*.

Comment: @joojaa I think some client underestimates usage of logo on all those different mediums. So they think if it's working for their current medium/need it's fine.

Comment: The thing about the Apple logo is it works just as well with 6 stripes, a glass finish or simple black & white 

Comment: Thing is though thats what differentiates a designer from a person who draws random stuff is that they can tell the client that the high contrast logo is needed. For design and usability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations and things to consider, which are of course opinion based, so feel free to ignore some or all of these.

1. The facial features don't look so good at small sizes. They just kind of disappear. Perhaps you could enlarge those a bit, i.e. bigger nose, bigger lips. Don't go crazy though, or it will look freaky.
2. Not sure why you got rid of the paint drips, maybe keep a simplified version of those.
3. You could simplify the colours more, avoiding unnecessary detail inside the logo. Maybe even just a single colour. This will also have the added benefit of making it easier and ultimately cheaper to print.
4. Check it works in your desired colour, in black only, and in reverse.
5. Check it works at different sizes

Here's a very rough idea

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I will keep the pointers in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to work on places where your shapes touch. There are many places where this happens but especially the place I've circled (small circle) where four different colors are touching. I would start with this, then work on spots where three colors are touching and see if that works better. This is not going to make your logo more "minimal" but it should make it simpler to comprehend.

Maybe it's just me but I get a bit distracted by the darker "drip" going close to the forehead (big circle). It almost seems like it should suggest an eye but it doesn't quite align.

Another option which might be worth exploring would be to offset one color slightly to see if it helps without breaking the mood. Also I feel like the middle color is not quite saturated enough to fit with your two other blues.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I will keep the pointers in mind.